# Are these the same equations?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If I have $2x^2+6x+2=0$ and $x^2+3x+1=0$ and then I multiply both sides of $x^2+3x+1=0$ by 2, I get $2x^2+6x+2=0$, which is the same as the first equation. However, when I graph $2x^2+6x+2$ and $x^2+3x+1$, they aren't the same graphs. Why is that?

Comment: One is a scaled version of the other. Your observation that $2(x^2+3x+1) = 0$ is the same as $2x^2 + 6x + 2 = 0$ tells you that $x^2 + 3x+1$ and $2x^2 + 6x + 2$ have the same roots.

Comment: Wait, how is the one a scaled version? What does that mean?

Comment: It means one is the other multiplied by some number. The two equations with $=0$ are logically equivalent, the two equations with $y=$ are not equivalent. Graphically, the graph of the scaled quadratic will be the same graph as the former, but stretched away from the $x$-axis by a factor of $2$.

Comment: What is your definition of **same equation**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $2x^2+6x+2=0$ and $x^2+3x+1=0$ are **same equations** but when you are plotting you are plotting the functions $y(x) =2x^2+6x+2$ and  $y(x)=x^2+3x+1$ which are **different functions**. One is a scaled version of the other.

To have same roots you need to have the curves intersect $y=0$ at the same points, which these two curves would do.

Comment: They are not the same equations.

Comment: @YoloInver these **equations** $2x^2+6x+2=0$ and $x^2+3x+1=0$ are indeed the same equations. However, the **functions** $f(x)=2x^2+6x+2$ and $g(x)=x^2+3x+1$ are not the same.

Comment: @YoloInver You’re right, they are different equations but share the same solution set.

Answer (score 1):

$2x^2+6x+2$ and $x^2+3x+1$ **have the same roots, this does not mean that they are the same equations.**

$2x^2+6x+2\ne x^2+3x+1$, since $2x^2+6x+2=2(x^2+3x+1)$, it is vertically stretched twice as much as $x^2+3x+1$